# CodeIgniter $this->input->post()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this in my order_invoice.php

```
   enter code here
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Email to Customer</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;     </button>

       <form  action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/email_invoice/"    method="POST" >

    <center> <input 
                               class="form-control"
                               name="email"
                               placeholder="Customer Email Address"

                            type= <?php echo form_input('email',    set_value('email', '')); ?>    /></center>

    </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/email_invoice/<?php echo $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>" type="submit"  name="submit"  class="btn btn-info " >Email to Customer</a></div>


    </form>
```

and i have this in my controller order.php

```
   //sender email
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        //subject
        $subject = 'Invoice no:' . $id;
        // set view page
        $view_page = $this->load->view('admin/order/pdf_order_invoice', $data, true);
        $send_email = $this->mail->sendEmail($from, $to, $subject, $view_page);
        if ($send_email) {
            $this->message->custom_success_msg('admin/order/order_invoice/' . $id,
                'Your email has been send successfully!');
        } else {
            $this->message->custom_error_msg('admin/order/order_invoice/' . $id,
                'Sorry unable to send your email!');
        }
    }else{
             $this->message->custom_error_msg('admin/order/order_invoice/' . $id,
            'Sorry unable to send your email, without company email');
    }
```

When i click submit the email not able to sent but if i replace `$to = $_POST['email']; to`$to = myemail@gmail.com;`

it able to sent the email. Please help ...

Comment: bro try to echo your post and comment all other codes to check whether you get your post value

Comment: and one more thing remore '/' after email_invoice in your form action

Comment: also you can dump the whole `$_POST` array to see what you get, and know that is contain `email` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you validate the email address before proceeding:

```
//sender email
$to = $_POST['email'];
if (!filter_var($to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    show_error("Email was not valid");
}
```

This may help you determine if your form is constructed properly and should also protect against abuse of your form.

If you don't get an error, then you know that $to contains a valid email address. This does NOT mean that the mail will actually be delivered. There are many many many factors that determine whether mail gets through or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an anchor to submit (which does not work, it will simply go to the page without submitting the form). You need to change this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/email_invoice/<?php echo $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>" type="submit"  name="submit"  class="btn btn-info " >Email to Customer</a>
```

to this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info " >Email to Customer</button>
```

Comment: twistedpixel, thank you so much, but the form still need to trigger this link :<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/email_invoice/<?php echo $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>"                                                                                               to get the invoice sent.. how do i fix this..

Comment: but when i set $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';  this link triggered and i get the email. it just still unable to figured out how to get the $to to grap the post email....

Comment: i also have try this with no luck :(                                                                                           `, <script>
  windows.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById('form-id').submit();
   return false;
   }; 
  };
  </script>`

Comment: You don't need an event handler. Buttons of type 'submit' will submit the form when you click them. If you need the invoice number as a parameter at the end of the url then you just add it to the URL in the action attribute of the form.

Comment: i did this with no luck...& the form not get submitted   `<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info " action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/email_invoice/<?php echo $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>" >`

Comment: No, the action attribute on the form element, not the button element. I mean this in the nicest way but I think you should really get to grips with HTML markup before trying to tether it to PHP. You will really struggle going forward without knowledge of the basics of HTML. An excellent resource that you'll find very useful is the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: School boy error :p... Thank you so much twistedpixel, solve the issue...